# Highlight passages from the body as quotes between the paragraphs

Tags: positioning, highlighting, quoting

In newspaper and magazine articles, striking messages from the main text are often highlighted in form of quotes in larger font size, sometimes also set apart by a bold rule or so. For an article I am composing, I would like to do the same.

Can you recommend any aesthetically pleasing method to do so?

Comment: Can you point to an example?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is one attempt at typesetting "emphasized quotes" within a document.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{multicol}% http://ctan.org/pkg/multicol
\newcommand{\myquote}[2][black!10]{%
  \medskip
  {\setlength{\fboxsep}{.1\columnwidth}%
  \noindent\colorbox{#1}{\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\columnwidth-2\fboxsep}
    \raggedright\sffamily\bfseries\Huge#2
  \end{minipage}}} \par
  \medskip
}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{3}
  \lipsum[1]
  \myquote{``This is a very important quote''}
  \lipsum[2-5]
  \myquote[orange!30]{``\ldots and here is another.''}
  \lipsum[6-9]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Since you reference newspaper or magazine as the source, [`multicol`](http://ctan.org/pkg/multicol) provides an easy-to-use columnar presentation. [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) was used to increase the page footprint (setting the text block margins to `1in`), while [`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) provided some dummy text.

The idea behind `\myquote[<color>]{<text>}` is to typeset the quote using a bunch of predefined font selections: `\raggedright\sffamily\bfseries\Huge`, all of which is mean to make them stand out from the regular text in terms of font size, type, family and alignment. The default background colour is 10% black (`black!10`, provided by [`xcolor`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor)), but you can change this to suit your document colours.

Of course, other "magic" can also be added to the formatting as defaults that are modifiable, if needed.