# Wrapping two column text around a centering picture

Tags: two-column, wrap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you create pull quotes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45709/how-do-you-create-pull-quotes)
>   [Two-column text with circular insert](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53073/two-column-text-with-circular-insert)

I'ld like to wrap text around a picture which is in the middle of the page, but I don't wanna let emtpy space next to it. So I mean something like this:

https://mail-attachment.googleusercontent.com/attachment/u/0/?ui=2&ik=1bc55d42c8&view=att&th=13b27ce82e811de6&attid=0.1&disp=inline&realattid=f_h9ts3uk40&safe=1&zw&saduie=AG9B_P828RkLDfGpDuIR_iNWBYDB&sadet=1353582607216&sads=GVM_m-x_ksm9hdKW25mG8fkfgC0

I've tried wrapfig environment, but usually it worked only with one column text for me.
Can anyone help? I'ld really apriciate.

Dénes from Hungary

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for something like [Two-column text with circular insert](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53073/two-column-text-with-circular-insert)?

Comment: Glad it helps! If you don't mind, we'll probably close this question as a duplicate then? (Welcome to the site, by the way)

Comment: Of course I don't mind, thanks anyway.