# How to use the pullquote package on a two-column layout?

Tags: two-column, wrap, quoting, pullquote

I've been reading about pull quotes. In [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53073/two-column-text-with-circular-insert), a great answer is posted with a link to a custom package called [pullquote](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~tex-sx/tex-sx/development/view/head:/pullquote.dtx).

I've installed this package and have been trying to make it work, as part of a document which already has two columns. Here's what I want to achieve:

[image]

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{pullquote}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\def\addquote
{%
  \Large
  \begin{tabular}[b]{p{5cm}}
    \textit{Wir m\"ussen wissen.}\\
    \textit{Wir werden wissen.}\\
    \mbox{}\hfill\large\textsc{David Hilbert}\\
  \end{tabular}%
}

\lipsum

\begin{pullquote}
  {
    object={\addquote}
  }
  \lipsum[1-3]
\end{pullquote}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

This gives me THREE columns wherever the pull quote appears:

[image]

I've taken code from [this discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/409/from-answers-to-packages) about the issue, but can not make it work. Any idea how to implement a pull quote in a two-column layout?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate: [How do you create pull quotes?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45709/how-do-you-create-pull-quotes).

Comment: @m0nhawk I've read that question and others here, but my question is specifically about the `pullquote` package, and about documents that are already formatted with two columns. The only other information on this same topic I found here came up in the discussion that I linked above, but not in a question with an answer.

Comment: Please, change your username to something more significant.

Comment: First: I get an output only with XeTeX and deactivated `microtype` (`pullquote` package option `nomicrotype`). You should have mentioned this. Second: This is a _package in development_ (you could have known this from the package resource): What you show is clearly a bug, and **for this kind of issues TeX.SX is the wrong place**. In documentation an e-mail address is given, or you try to contact Stephan in chat of TeX.SX.

Comment: Just to confirm I've seen this question ;-) I agree it would be better posed as a bug report on the launchpad site or in the [answers to packages chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/409/from-answers-to-packages).

Comment: A general question on how to get this kind of layout would not be too localized though.

Comment: @user Would it be okay if I reformulated your question to be more general?

Comment: Thanks all for feedback. @Speravir I thought I was simply not using `pullquote` properly, rather than this being a bug. But if it is, I understand this is not the right place to post this. @StephanLehmke, yes, please go ahead to change this questions to make it more general. I'll try to followup with a bug report at some point. Thanks.