# How to center a wrapfig image?

Tags: wrapfigure

I am trying to place an image in the horizontal center of a two-column document.

I tried:

```
\subsection{title}
\begin{center}
    \begin{wrapfigure}{}{}
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{FIGURE.jpg}
    \end{wrapfigure}
\end{center}
```

but this does not work. 
Any ideas of how to do it ?

EDIT:

Thanks to @Bernard, I tried:
(you have to include \usepackage{cuted} )

```
\begin{strip}
    \begin{figure*}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{FIGURE.jpg}
    \caption{caption}
    \label{label}
    \end{figure*}
\end{strip}
```

...but it does not work

Comment: Why do you want wrapfigure if it should be centred? Why not figure?

Comment: @Bernard. The document has two columns. I don't see any other method than to use wrapfigure. If I use figure, then this figure will be inserted into a column and not span the two columns.

Comment: You can use the `figure*`  environment (note that it will be placed at the top of the following page).

Comment: @Bernard Thanks. Hmm, I was hoping to avoid that. I would like to place the image where I want.

Comment: In this case, use the `strip` environment, from `cuted` (`sttools` bundle).

Comment: @Bernard Please have a look at my updated question

Comment: Remove  the `figure*`  environment: `strip` is *not* a floating environment, so you should use `\captionof{figure}{label}`.(load the `caption` package). After that, it should work.

Comment: Your question is very unclear but are you looking for this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45709/how-do-you-create-pull-quotes

Comment: You might want to take a look at a brand new package on CTAN: `wrapstuff.sty`. Currently, the documentation is only in Chinese (though it is possible to see how to use the package) and the package is labelled as *experimental.* You also need to have an absolutely up-to-date LaTeX installation for this to work. It does work in the simple examples I tried. Quite magical.