# Text fitted around the middle image or note

Tags: macros, graphics, tex-core

Please see this article

[image: nature]

In my own case, I have a text middle of which I wish to insert a square containing a note. How we can do that!!!

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45709/how-do-you-create-pull-quotes and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53073/two-column-text-with-circular-insert

Comment: Thank you so much for inviting us to see the references . They are very good. However, in one of them I faced with problems in using pullquote

Comment: If it's a one-off thing, I would just do it manually, specifying parshape for each paragraph one-by-one, after seeing where it happens to fall on the page. It gets the job done and you can move on to other things. But for some reason people don't seem to like such solutions. :-)